# Simplify expression, complex variable

Tags: complex-analysis

I need helping with simplifying expression:

$$\frac{(1+i)^{33}}{(1-i)^{33}}+(1-i)^{10}+(2+3i)(2-3i)-i^{-7}$$

What I got is:
$$\frac{(1+i)^{33}}{(1-i)^{33}}+(1-i)^{10}+(2+3i)(2-3i)-i^{-7}=\frac{(1+i)^{33}}{(1-i)^{33}}+(1-i)^{10}+13-i^{-7}$$

My problems begin with $$\frac{(1+i)^{33}}{(1-i)^{33}}$$ -- is it possible to simplify it without de Moivre or Euler's formulas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write

$$\frac{(1+i)^{33}}{(1-i)^{33}} = \left(\frac{1+i}{1-i}\right)^{33} = \left(\frac{2i}{2}\right)^{33} = i^{33} = i,$$
where the 3rd expression comes from rationalizing the denominator, multiplying by $\frac{1+i}{1+i}$.

Comment: In you comment, you meant this, right: $$(\frac{1+i}{1-i})^{33}=(\frac{1+i}{1-i}*\frac{1+i}{1+i})^{33}$$ ?

Comment: @user219009 Yes, exactly.